# How to request in jquery an url with @?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my jQuery script I have an Ajax call to an url like : http://tokenvalue@example.com.

When I made a request with `$.ajax` or `$.get`, jquery remove the `tokenvalue`. So authentication failed.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://tokenvalue@example.com"
},
```

Why does jQuery remove it ? And how to fix that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `encodeURIComponent`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: Thansk for your help but it doesn't work. My question is not about encoding the URI. It's about keeping the username in the url.

Comment: `http://tokenvalue@example.com` is not a valid URL

Comment: It's an url with an username and no password. Maybe it's not valid but Dataiku Api give url like that. But I finally fix my problem using ```xhrFields.withCredentials```.